# Bind asp:Parameter in asp:SqlDataSource to Database field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I use an `asp:SqlDataSource` Element to fetch Data and then display it in an `asp:ListView`.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the Database consists of the rows and `id`, `author` (it's actually more, but that doesn't matter).

This is the code I use:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="NewsDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ connectionStrings:RemoteSqlConnection %>"
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [news]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [news] SET author=@author WHERE id=@id"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [news] WHERE id=@id"
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [news] (author) VALUES (@author)">

    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My problem is, that the parameter `id` which I define for `UpdateParameters` and `DeleteParameters` is always `null`. 
It doesn't seem to be associated with the database field `id`.

One hack which allowed me to fix the problem (but only for the update case) was to insert an invisible `asp:Label` to which I binded the `id` (Just like I binded the Author field to a Textbox).

I don't think that the ListView code should be relevant, but I'll try to include some lines which are relevant here:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" DataSourceID="NewsDataSource">

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("author")%>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <EditItemTemplate>
                <!-- This line is only the workaround solution --><asp:Label ID="idLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("id")%>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="authorTextbox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("author")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an attribute on the `asp:ListView` called `DataKeyNames`, adding `id` to this should make it store that parameter value without the need for a hidden element.

For more information on the `DataKeyNames` attribute see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was missing